# Cannot index string : Wrong command with jq?

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I've this type of data :

```
[
  "foo1:         xxxxxx",
  "foo2:    xxxxxx",
  "foo3:     xxxxxx",
  "foo4:         xxxxxx",
  "foo5:   xxxxxx",
  "foo6:       xxxxxx"
]
```

I would like to parse it with jq. I've tried that :

```
cat file.txt | jq '.foo1'
```

```
cat file.txt | jq '.[] | .foo1'
```

And I've this error everytime :

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:8): Cannot index string with string "foo1"
exit status 5
```

But I don't know why !

There is someone to show me what is wrong with my jq command ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show the expected output, in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: You have an array of literal strings, that can't be retrieved like a map

Answer (score 2):

The input you provided is an array of strings. The command `.foo1` is trying to get the `foo1` field of an input object, but the input is an array, not an object. Likewise, the command `.[] | .foo1` is trying to iterate through the input array (this is fine) and then get the `foo1` field of each item object, but these items are strings, not objects.

If you want to get the `xxxxxx` that is in the string beginning with `foo1:`, you can do something like this:

```
$ jq '.[] | select(startswith("foo1")) | sub("foo1:\\s+"; "")' file.txt
"xxxxxx"
```

If you want to turn your input into an actual JSON object, you can iterate over each string, use `capture` to get the key and value, and then use `from_entries` to stitch it all back together into a single object. At this point, you can append your original `.foo1` and you'll get the behavior you originally expected.

```
$ jq 'map(capture("^(?<key>.*):\\s*(?<value>.*)$")) | from_entries' file.txt
{
  "foo1": "xxxxxx",
  "foo2": "xxxxxx",
  "foo3": "xxxxxx",
  "foo4": "xxxxxx",
  "foo5": "xxxxxx",
  "foo6": "xxxxxx"
}
```